# Copy from Json.Serde formatted table into a text file formatted hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am completely new with hive.

I have created a hive table on top of my json files using `Json.SerDe` and also loaded the data.

Below is the structure

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE JsonTable_raw (
  data array<struct<
      start_date:string,
      end_date:string,
      measures:struct<
      Visitors:int,
      Singlepagevisits:int
      >
    >
  >
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
```

I have created one more table which is not formatted using `JsonSerDe`.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE JsonTable (
  start_date string,
  end_date string,
  Visitors int,
  Singlepagevisits int
)
```

I tried to use the below query

```
INSERT INTO TABLE JsonTable select
  data.start_date,data.end_date,data.measures.Visitors,
data.measures.Singlepagevisits FROM JsonTable_raw;
```

but it threw

> NoMatchingMethodException No matching method for class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFToInteger with (array). Possible
>   choices: *FUNC*(bigint)  *FUNC*(boolean)  *FUNC*(decimal(38,18)) 
>   *FUNC*(double)  *FUNC*(float)  *FUNC*(smallint)  *FUNC*(string)  *FUNC*(timestamp)  *FUNC*(tinyint)  *FUNC*(void)

Now how do I copy the data from JsonTable_raw to JsonTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour of searching and trying I was able to do it myself.  Below is the script

```
INSERT INTO TABLE JsonTable 
select cols.start_date,cols.end_date,cols.measures.Visitors,
cols.measures.Singlepagevisits
FROM JsonTable_raw jt lateral view explode(jt.data) collection as cols;
```